# -bash: zerorpc: command not found?

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, zerorpc

I have installed zerorpc using both pip and npm and both are sucessfull. but i am still not able to run zerorpc from cli. 
I have also tried installing with virutalenv but still no luck.
it works well within python cli. bt when i try to use something like `zerorpc tcp://127.0.0.1:4242 hello RPC` it throws a straight error saying

> -bash: zerorpc: command not found

Comment: typically a cli associated with a package goes in the scripts subdirectory.  is that directory on your path?

Comment: should i add `/Users/masoodahmed/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-package` directory to my $PATH ?

Comment: there should be a python scripts directory somewhere in your python installation.  the zerorpc (assuming it has its own command that comes as part of it) should likely be there.  that is the directory you want on your path.  likely the same place that PIP is installed and the pip command exists.

Comment: was that helpful?